# Does Nevada (Las Vegas in particular) accept vertical IDs?

Tags: paperwork, alcohol, las-vegas

Just weeks before my 21st birthday I received my new California license, and since I was still under 21 it was vertical. Last year in Tahoe I wasn't able to purchase alcohol at a bar because my ID was vertical, even though I was six months past the age of 21. But this year I am going to go to Vegas a week after my 23rd birthday and I'll still have a vertical license.

Would my ID be declined anywhere there?

It's not eligible for renewal this year, so I would have to go through some trouble to get a new horizontal one, and I'd really rather not do that.

Comment: You could always get a passport.

Answer (score 2):

Was asked at [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g45963-i10-k7578280-Will_I_be_able_to_use_my_ID-Las_Vegas_Nevada.html) where the answer seems to have been, "at first, possibly" - but a little persistence, if required, would be sufficient. (Acceptance or not may depend more on whom you present it to than the law.)